# only first caption showing for attachment in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

ok I'm using the below code to generate caption for my attachments. The problem is if I have multiple images in a single page, the caption for first image shows for all the images. like if I have "Text One" as a caption for my image one, all the image showing this "Text One" caption. How can I solve this problem?

```
 <?php 
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 
                    'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
                    'order' => 'ASC', 
                    'post_mime_type' => 'image' ,
                    'post_status' => null, 
                    'numberposts' => 50, 
                    'post_parent' => $post->ID );

        $attachments = get_posts($args);
        if ($attachments) {
            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                $caption = $attachment->post_excerpt;
                } 
             }
    ?>
    <p class="project-caption"><?php echo $caption ?></p>
```

currently there is a slider, which shows the images. & the slider code is:

```
<?php
                if($repeater):
                    foreach($repeater as $r):
            ?>
                <li class="<?php echo $r["fit_to_screen"] ? "img_fit" : ""; ?>">
                    <?php
                    if($r["acf_fc_layout"] == "image"):
                    $html = "<img data-fit='".$r["fit_to_screen"]."' src='".$r["image"]["url"]."' alt='".$r["image"]["alt"]."'/>";
                    echo apply_filters( 'post_thumbnail_html', $html, $post->ID , $r["image"]["id"], "large" , array("alt"=>$r["image"]["alt"]) );
                    else:
                        echo getVideoEmbed($r["video_url"]);
                    endif;
                    ?>
                </li>
            <?php
                    endforeach;
                endif;
            ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You override the `$caption` in the loop so at the end you get the last caption.

You can print the `$caption` inside the loop and then you get all the captions.

```
foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
    $caption = $attachment->post_excerpt;
    echo '<p class="project-caption">'.$caption.'</p>';
}
```

Comment: but if I use this code, all my captions are showing at once.[link](http://img0.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/20173/20173570ed928077bc4a6eccb30852aaff405fb4.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You get the same caption because you are displaying the caption after the foreach, and you should do it in the foreach:

```
<?php 
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 
                'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
                'order' => 'ASC', 
                'post_mime_type' => 'image' ,
                'post_status' => null, 
                'numberposts' => 50, 
                'post_parent' => $post->ID );

    $attachments = get_posts($args);
    if ($attachments) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
            $caption = $attachment->post_excerpt;
            echo '<p class="project-caption">' . $caption . '</p>';
            } 
         }
?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. but if I use your code, all the caption showing at  once. actually it is a slider, so only one image shows at a time & when you click next button the next image shows. I have added the slider code in my post, please check out.

Comment: Put your captions inside the slider li. And Make them slide with the image. Or if you don't want to do that add some classes so you can know that a caption is related to a certain li, and when the li is active simply display that caption.

Comment: here is a screenshot [link](http://img0.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/20173/20173570ed928077bc4a6eccb30852aaff405fb4.jpg)

Comment: Try adding the caption inside the li for each image, so it will only show for the current image.

Comment: can you tell me how? I'm not very familiar with php & using this code from google search.

Comment: I need more details to help you. You are using teh advanced custom fields repeater for your images?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64515/discussion-between-aohor-arsalan-and-sticksu).